# Python: I get a KeyError: 'Yes' when I try to use value_count with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'deliveryzipcode':['75202', '75202', '75202', '60660', '60660', '60660', '60660'],
                        'orderreturned': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']})
df
```

```py
print(df.groupby('deliveryzipcode')['orderreturned'].value_counts()['Yes'] )
```

[image]

searched for Python Key Error to see what others have encountered adn did to erolve the problem.

Comment: Please copy paste error in your question instead of an image.

Comment: What do you want to do? Select only `Yes` counts for each delivery code?

Comment: This is because `value_counts()` returns a multi-indexed DataFrame, because you grouped by both fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your DataFrame, we can use the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with the `as_index` parameter set to `False`, and filter the `df` on the `Yes` value to get a clean DataFrame like so :

```py
df[df['orderreturned']=='Yes'].groupby('deliveryzipcode', as_index=False)['orderreturned'].value_counts()
```

Output :

```
    deliveryzipcode     orderreturned   count
0   60660               Yes             1
1   75202               Yes             2
```

Comment: This helps, but how would I get only the yes counts grouped by zip code?

Comment: Hello @Dan :) ! I updated the answer, is it what you expected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Dataframe.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to select only certain rows by index:

```py
grouped_df = df.groupby("deliveryzipcode")["orderreturned"].value_counts()
print(grouped_df.xs("Yes", level=1))
```

Prints:

```
60660    1
75202    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```